# can we use recursion with AWS lambda function that it stops execution within 15 minutes time limit and save the point at which it stopped?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, timeout

1. track the time elapsed in lambda function stop it at 9-10 min .
2. save the point at which it stopped and continue untill task is completed
3. compulsory use lambda function

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve from a business use-case? Are you trying to run something that takes too long for Lambda? If so, it is probably not a good use-case for Lambda and you should consider using EC2 or Fargate instead.

Comment: i know all of these but my task is to use lambda functions only .

Comment: have to use lambda so that my script runs without human intervention

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I support John Rotenstein's response, stating that if you're using lambda this way, you probably shouldn't be using lambda. Out of my own curiosity though, I think the code you'd be looking for is something along the following lines (written in Node.JS)

```js
let AWS = require('aws-sdk');
let functionName = 'YOUR_LAMBDA_FUNCTION_NAME'
let timeThreshholdInMillis = 5000 // 5 seconds

exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
    let input = JSON.parse(event['foo']); // input from previous lambda, omitted try-catch for brevity
    let done // set this variable to true when your code is done

    let interval = setInterval(() => {
        if (done) callback(null, true)

        let remainingTime = context.get_remaining_time_in_millis();

        if (remainingTime < timeThreshholdInMillis) {
            // Going to restart
            clearInterval(interval);
            // save your progress (local or remote) to `input` variable
            let lambda = new AWS.Lambda();
            return lambda.invoke({
                FunctionName: functionName,
                Payload: JSON.stringify({ 'foo': input }) // Pass your progress here
            }, (err, data) => {
                // kill container
                if (err) callback(err)
                else callback(null, data)
            });
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```

### Edit: an example

*This is to clarify how 'passing progress' would work in recursive lambdas.*

Let's say you want to increment a variable (+1) every second and you want to do this in Lambda.

**Givens**
We will increment the variable by 1 once every 1000 ms.
Lambda will run until remaining time is < 5000 ms.
Lambda execution timeout is 60,000 ms (1 minute).

Lambda function pseudo code:

```js
function async (event, context) {
    let counter = event.counter || 0

    setInterval(() => {
        if (context.get_remaining_time_in_millis() < 5000) {
             // start new lambda and pass `counter` variable
             // so it continues counting and we don't lose progress
             lambda.invoke({ payload: { counter } })
        } else {
            // Add 1 to the counter variable
            counter++
        }
    }, 1000)

}
```

Comment: HI Tom can you help me with this how will i save my progress and will the function start from where it stopped . can you help me with usage of s3 and s3 event triggers in this task

Comment: I've added an example for clarity @anonymous

Comment: do we have a way in lambdas to  pass the state of the currently executing function so that the subsequent function can continue from that point onwards. how will we save the state and where?

Comment: @anonymous Please check out the example I have added. The state in this case is the variable 'counter'. Each lambda will increment it and pass it to the next lambda through the payload.

Comment: i understood that for example in my script i have to 5-6 functions which i have to execute in a single lambda so i need to figure out that my which function is executing and  pass that data to next lambda that restart from that point

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying out, but have a look at AWS Step Functions to better orchestrate your serverless recursion fun.
Also be aware of costs.

Getting Started: 
https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/create-a-serverless-workflow-step-functions-lambda/

Example:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/sample-project-transfer-data-sqs.html

Comment: thank you for your answer these links were helpful but can we not do it with just one lambda function

Comment: basically i have to perform some task for different accounts is there any way i can check if for which account all the task is done and in next execution i start from the next account

Comment: You can iterate through an array and trigger processing. See: [How to use AWS Step Functions to iterate and sequentially process jobs](https://read.acloud.guru/processing-an-arbitrary-number-of-jobs-with-aws-step-functions-c185c2d2608)

Comment: hi john i guess this would solve my problem . i still have a doubt for one account my script takes approx 9-10 min so time would not be a problem i guess .BTW thank u so much

Comment: @JohnRotenstein if you could help with the solution

Comment: @JohnRotenstein you have mentioned step functions instead of lambdas to avoid recursion . I have a large amount of data that I need to pull fown ftpm a